# LINQ-2-SQL How-To "Reuse" sub selections

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

Let's assume:

- I have an EVENT table
- I have a CLIENT table
- And ADDRESS table have some column: UnitNo, StreetNo, StreetName, City, AddressType etc
- A CLIENT has many EVENTs and CLIENT can have many ADDRESSes also

So if I want to query list of events with client HOME address street name, I just go

```
var qry = db.Events
            .Select(evt => new {
               EventAddress =
               evt.Client
                  .Addresses
                  .FirstOrDefault(a => a.AddressType.Equals("HOME")).StreetName
            });
```

However, if I want to get the full address I will need to concatenate sereval address fields. At the moment I am trying something like

```
var qry = db.Events
            .Select(evt => new {
               EventAddress =
               evt.Client
                  .Addresses
                  .FirstOrDefault(a => a.AddressType.Equals("HOME")).StreetNo + " " +
               evt.Client
                  .Addresses
                  .FirstOrDefault(a => a.AddressType.Equals("HOME")).StreetName + " " +
               evt.Client
                  .Addresses
                  .FirstOrDefault(a => a.AddressType.Equals("HOME")).City
            });
```

It doesn't work and looks ugly too
Is there a better way to make the
`evt.Client.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(a => a.AddressType.Equals("HOME"))` "reusable" so I can just go

```
var qry =
    db.Events
      .Select(evt => new {
         EventAddress = 
         STUFF.StreetNo + " " + STUFF.StreetName + " " + STUFF.City
});
```

Many thanks in advance!

Hugh

**UPDATE:**

Thanks Ilian for the answer, it works well. And based on that I have created the extension version of the answer

```
var qry =
    db.Events
      .Select(evt => new {
         EventAddress = 
         db.Addresses.Select(a => new
           {
             ClientId = a.ClientId,
             AddressType = a.AddressType,
             FullAddress = (a.addStreetNo ?? "") + (a.addStreetName ?? "")
           })
         .FirstOrDefault(a => a.ClientId == e.Client.ClientId && a.AddressType.Equals("HOME"))
         .FullAddress
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the query syntax:

```
var qry =
    from evt in db.Events
    let firstAddress = evt.Client.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(a => a.AddressType.Equals("HOME"))
    where firstAddress != null
    select new
    {
        EventAddress = firstAddress.StreetNo + " " +
                       firstAddress.StreetName + " " +
                       firstAddress.City
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it ago. But do we have the extension version of this by any chance?

Comment: Doing this with extension methods will look ugly. I wouldn't think of using it in this scenario. The query syntax was made for situations like this.

Comment: Alright, I will try to integrate this because it is just a subset of my big query all in extension methods. Thanks again